# How do I configure mylyn jenkins?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, mylyn, eclipse-luna

I want to integrate Jenkins in with Eclipse. I found a mylyn hudson/jenkins connector and have installed that in Eclipse Luna. I restarted Eclipse and then attempted to add my jenkins server as a mylyn repository. But it doesn't show the jenkins connector when I click "Add Repository". Is there a tutorial out there on how I can set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are in the wrong view. Open "Builds" view to connect to Hudson or Jenkins.